# Hive Parameter in hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two code.

One is named testing.hql

```
select dt, '${hiveconf:var}' from temp_table;
```

other is named testing.sh

```
temp= date --date='yesterday' +%y%m%d
hive -f testing.hql -hiveconf var=$temp
```

so basically im trying to pass date value to the query so i can filter the data i process in the query based on the current date.

im running this by this command. easy.

```
./testing.sh
```

This doesn't work,, can someone quickly check and see which part am i making a mistake?

So basically what I want to do is

```
select jobid from temp_table where dt >= '${hiveconf:var}';
```

so that the jobid  i get are only the ones that are done from yesterday, since the 
shell script sets paramter as the date for yesterday.

Thanks!

Currently this outputs the empty space after the dt value.

Comment: Can you give a column name you want to query?

Comment: So basically what im trying to do is compare dt with the parameter, ill edit the post for more specificity

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

2 simple bugs.

1) When doing shell scripts, executing lines have to be wrapped with `.
 so i did

```
    temp=`date --date='yesterday' +%y%m%d`
    hive -f testing.hql -hiveconf var=$temp
```

and it works like a charm

2) in the query, the parameter must be in double quotes.

```
    select jobid from temp_table where dt >= "${hiveconf:var}";
```

Hope this question can help others who had this issue.

Comment: I asked for clarification because the date command's result you passed to the query is actually a numeric value. In testing.hql you referred to it as a column name but column names couldn't be numeric values. Now I see that you are using it in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeeTamer for that. It allows to store result (or part of it) in a variable, and use this variable later in your code.

Beetamer is macro extension to Hive or Impala that allows to extend functionality of the Apache Hive and Cloudera Impala engines.

```
select avg(a) from abc;
%capture MY_AVERAGE;
select * from abc2 where avg_var=#MY_AVERAGE#;
```

In here you save average value from you query into macro variable MY_AVERAGE and then reusing it in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space after temp= removing that possibly should solve the issue

```
temp=<blank>date ...
```

Answer (score 0):

temp variable should be declared as below,

```
temp=$(date --date='yesterday' +%y%m%d)
```